# kick out users in Kentico chat window

Tags: chat, kentico

Anyone know how to kick out users in Kentico chat window.

when admin open the chat window, there is list of online user so what if admin want to kick out one of the users how i can add a button to kick them out.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why the kick out button is not appearing in the chat window. I checked the code in file "ChatRoomUsers.js" and if the room marked as 'is Support' then the kick out button disappear

the thing is if the room setting NOT is support then no notification will be send to the chat admin so i changed the code in file 'ChatRoomUsers.js' to display the kickout & assign user as room admin regardless the room setting 'IS support' true or false.

Sam